# How do I get the text from a textfile into a String?

Tags: android, newline, inputstream, bufferedreader, arrays

I'm trying to get it so my app can read the words from my textfile separated by a carriage enter and spit them back out from a String array. My app starts up then just gives me a blank page which is pretty frustrating.  Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView helloTxt= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hellotxt);


        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);


            if (is != null) {

              InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
              BufferedReader buffythevampireslayer = new BufferedReader(isr);

              String line;


              do {
                 line = buffythevampireslayer.readLine();
                 list.add(line);

              } while (line != null);

            }
            is.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            } 
        String[] wordsArray=new String[list.size()];
        list.toArray(wordsArray);
        Thread timer=new Thread(); {
        for (int c=0;c<list.size();c++){
            helloTxt.setText(wordsArray[c]);
            System.out.println("TEXTSET");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        };
        timer.start();
        }
    }
```

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help, thanks so much!!!

EDIT::::
After getting some help in this post, I now have the working app!  Thanks so much! Here is the new code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;

import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ReadAndUpdateTextTask readAndUpdateTextTask = new ReadAndUpdateTextTask();
            readAndUpdateTextTask.execute();
       }

       class ReadAndUpdateTextTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

public     String currentString = "";
String line="";
InputStream isr;

       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
           isr = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
       }
       @Override

       protected String doInBackground(Void... params) { 
           try {

               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr));
               while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                   currentString += line + "\n"; 
                   publishProgress(currentString);

                   // I don't think you really need this but you want a sleep for 5000 ms
                   SystemClock.sleep(5000);
               }
               isr.close();
           } catch (Exception ex) {
           }

           return currentString;
       } 

       @Override
       protected void onProgressUpdate(String... currentString) { 
           TextView helloTxt= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hellotxt);
           helloTxt.setText(currentString[0]);
       } 
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
           TextView helloTxt= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hellotxt);
           helloTxt.setText(result);
       } 
       }
    }
```

Comment: instead of helloTxt.setText(wordsArray[c]); try helloTxt.append(wordsArray[c]);

Comment: Thanks for trying but none of the responses worked :(

Comment: You have a catch exception that doesn't do anything - I would advise you to at least put out a log so you know if any exceptions are being raised.  Once you do that, check if there are any exceptions in logcat?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve anything, but you can try declaring your List as shown [in Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html). I will look further in a bit.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but none of the responses worked :(

Answer (score 0):

if it's not a typo, your problem is here:

```
 String[] wordsArray=new String[list.size()];
 list.toArray(wordsArray);
```

it should be:

```
 String[] wordsArray = list.toArray( new String[0] );
```

otherwise the array is filled with nulls

Comment: Thanks for trying but none of the responses worked :(

Answer (score 0):

You got a blank screen because you have a sleep at your main UI thread. Do reading the file in an `AsyncTask` and publish its process.

Your `onCreate` method should look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ReadAndUpdateTextTask readAndUpdateTextTask = new ReadAndUpdateTextTask();
        readAndUpdateTextTask.execute();
   }

   class ReadAndUpdateTextTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {


   InputStream isr;

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       isr = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
   }
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(Void... params) { 
       try {
           String currentString = "";
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr));
           while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
               currentString += line + "\n"; 
               publishProgress(currentString);

               // I don't think you really need this but you want a sleep for 5000 ms
               SystemClock.sleep(5000);
           }
           isr.close();
       } catch (Exception ex) {
       }

       return currentString;
   } 

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(String... currentString) { 
       TextView helloTxt= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hellotxt);
       helloTxt.setText(currentString[0]);
   } 
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
       TextView helloTxt= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hellotxt);
       helloTxt.setText(result);
   } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but in the ReadAndUpdateTextTask class, the getResources and the findVIewById methods are both getting compiling errors still.  It says "The Method getResources() is undefined for ReadAndUpdateTextTask" and for both findViewById it says the same thing but findViewById instead of getResources().  Any ideas?

Comment: i've edited my answer. For res not found errors define ReadAndUpdateTextTask inside of your Activity.

Comment: This fixed those issues, but now it says that BufferedReader can only read a reader, and the inputstream isn't a reader.  I tried changing the InputStream into an InputStreamReader, but that also didn't fix the issue.  I'm also getting an error at the setText in the onProgressUpdate as well as for the currentString return (However I think these will both be fixed if the BufferedReader issue is fixed).  Thanks again so much!

Comment: Use a InputStreamReader while reading Also I've updated onProgressUpdate code. see my edits.

Comment: @user3344504 This should solve your problem, isn't it?

Comment: This was very close to solving my problem, but with a few tiny changes, I got it to finally work, thanks so much for all of your help!  The code has been posted and updated into the original post.

Comment: to close this question, select one of the answers, to mark this questions solved.

Answer (score 0):

- First, you need to store your text file in the assets folder
- then you need to call the AssetManager to get the assets in your assets folder

  ```
  AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
  InputStream inputStream = null;
  ```
- surround these statements with a try block, in case the file is not found in the stated path

  ```
     inputStream = assetManager.open("texts/sample.txt"); // path is relative to the assets folder
     ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
     int length = 0;
  ```
- read the the bytes and write them in an output stream

  ```
     while((length = inputStream.read(bytes)) > 0)
         bytesOutputStream.write(bytes,0,length);
  ```
- create a new String, use the constructor with the byteOutputStream
- encode it with UTF8(assuming there wont be any chinese, japanese, etc characters)
- See this for more details about [UTF Details](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

  ```
     String yourString = new String(bytesOutputStream.toByteArray(), "UTF8");
  ```
- Java String class has a method "split", which takes a regex as a parameter
- it splits the string and stores it into a single element in an array everytime it encounters a new line
- in your case, use '\n' which stands for new line

  ```
     String[] yourStringArray = yourString.split("\n");
  ```
- Surround everything with a try-catch clause (IOException), which is thrown in case file is not found
- you can now use yourStringArray as

  ```
      textView.setText(yourStringArray[index]);
  ```

Comment: This still did not work for me, it crashes upon start without the sleep for 5000 ms, but with the 5000 ms it waits 5000 ms then crashes.